# How to detect display driver info

Tags: kernel, x11, drivers, configuration, video

Is it possible to check the different status of video drivers when it is on, is off, in error, in no-signal?
Example: monitor off - some state 0-, monitor no-signal - some state not connected and so on?

Comment: Does your system run a **single** x11-server instance ? How many GPUs are made available ?

Comment: My system is a simple Intel nuc mini desktop  with no external video cards with lubuntu 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `grep . /sys/class/drm/card0-*/{status,enabled,dpms}`.
If this doesn't satisfy your needs, just leave a comment below.

Comment: It's available also in a system without Nvidia card, but only the Intel onboard video? So the classic Linux driver load by default?

Comment: The command works on both my laptop (Nvidia) and my desktop PC (AMD), so I don't see it not working on Intel computers.

Comment: @Alessandro Did it work?

Comment: It works with status enabled and connected but with standby or no signal?

Comment: @Alessandro You could try `xset q`.

Comment: What this command do? Thanks a lot.